# Covariance Generics c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

This is  an  example  taken  from  [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-in-interfaces-for-generic-collections), for covariance in generics in  C#.

I am unable to print FullName, can I know why the output is not printing?

```
// Simple hierarchy of classes.  
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person { }

public class Print
{
    // The method has a parameter of the IEnumerable<Person> type.  
    public static void PrintFullName(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        foreach (Person person in persons)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}",
            person.FirstName, person.LastName);
        }
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> employees = new List<Person>();
        Person person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "nuli";
        person.LastName = "swathi";
        Print.PrintFullName(employees);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Can I know why the output is not printing...." Well, I assume something **is** printed, however it´s not what you expected, is it?

Comment: The question isn't about variance.

Comment: You have to add person to the employees collection by using employees.Add(person);

Answer (score 3):

Because your `employees` list is empty.

You should add your Person instance to the `employees` list, then you'll see it printed.

i.e.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        IList<Person> employees = new List<Person>(); //you need to declare this as a List/IList to get the `Add` method
        Person person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "nuli";
        person.LastName = "swathi";

        //add this line
        employees.Add(person);

        Print.PrintFullName(employees);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can  I  just Know  that how to add? @S.L. Barth

Comment: @nulibunny Dont declare a local `List<T>` as an `IEnumerable<T>`, whats the point? Declare it as a list and simply call `Add`.

Comment: Then in msdn in the first example , they gave like that only. Refer  the  [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-in-interfaces-for-generic-collections)

Comment: @nulibunny In the code there, there is a comment: "You can pass IEnumerable<Employee>,   although the method expects IEnumerable<Person>." This is where the user is supposed to add their own code. That example is, perhaps, a bit too short.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you forgot the string.format? Try to use this:

```
Console.WriteLine( String.format("Name: {0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName))
```

instead of this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName);
```

or even better this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Name: {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

EDIT: Since its a mdn example its more likely the list is empty..

Comment: Good thinking! But, that isn't the problem: `Console.WriteLine(string, object, object)` will treat the input string as a formatting string; see [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_). The problem is (as we've both observed) that the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a List, List implements IEnumerable. There were a few mistakes within your **Program** class, You can find the corrected code below:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person { }

class Print
{
    // The method has a parameter of the IEnumerable<Person> type.  
    public static void PrintFullName(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
    {
        foreach (Person person in persons) {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0} {1}", person.FirstName, person.LastName)); // needs to format the string for it to work, hence string.format().....
        }
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Person> employees = new List<Person>(); // no need to convert it to an IEnumerable object as List already implements IEnumerable<>
        Person person = new Person();
        person.FirstName = "nuli";
        person.LastName = "swathi";
        employees.Add(person);  // You have to populate the list first
        Print.PrintFullName(employees);   
        Console.ReadLine();     // Changed from Console.ReadKey()
    }
}
```